# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'string'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying lookup the database that match specific `campus_id`. This works if I use integers, but doesn't work with strings.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Campus(models.Model):
   campus_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
   restaurant_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   campus_id = models.ForeignKey(Campus,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   opening_hours = models.TimeField()
   closing_hours = models.TimeField()
   capacity = models.IntegerField()
   #staff = models.IntegerField()

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def restaurants(request):
    query = request.GET.get('search', None)
    context = {}
    if query and request.method == 'GET':
        results = Restaurant.objects.filter(campus_id=query)
        context.update({'results':results})
        return render(request, 'eatatdcu/restaurants.html', context)
```

**restaurants.html**

```
{% for x in results %}


        {{x.name}} , {{x.location}}

        <br>

    {% endfor %}
```

**Traceback log**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\Desktop\CA377\2019-ca377-EatAtDCU\src\ca377\eatatdcu\views.py", line 13, in restaurants
        results = Restaurant.objects.filter(campus_id=query)
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 781, in filter
        return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 799, in _filter_or_exclude
        clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1260, in add_q
        clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1286, in _add_q
        allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1216, in build_filter
        condition = lookup_class(lhs, value)
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
        self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 110, in get_prep_lookup
        self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
      File "C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1849, in get_prep_value
        return int(value)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dcu alpha'
```

Comment: Please show us the full traceback.

Comment: Your `search` parameter contains `'string'`, so not an (integer) number, hence this will not work for `campus_id=query`.

Comment: The ORM tries to cast filter arguments to the appropriate types for the db fields. The query at hand works for strings that can be converted to `int`, but not for others.

Comment: Please show us your models.py

Comment: I have added the traceback and models.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the error message that you tried to search for the value `dcu alpha` in the field `Restaurant.campus_id` (which is a `ForeignKey`, so in the database it will have the type of the PK of the model `Campus`, which is an integer). Django tries to cast the search value to an `int` because the field is an integer.

Maybe you want to search a different field, maybe:

- `name` (the name of the `Restaurant` instances)
- or `campus_id__name` (the name of the `Campus` instance belonging to the `Restaurant` instances)?

Or you could add error handling:

```
def restaurants(request):
    query = request.GET.get('search', None)
    context = {}
    if query and request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            query_int = int(query)
        except ValueError:
            query_int = -1

        results = Restaurant.objects.filter(campus_id=query_int)
        context.update({'results':results})
        return render(request, 'eatatdcu/restaurants.html', context)
```